# Why is the period of a pendulum on the Moon $\sqrt{6}$ times its period on the Earth?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

I came across this equation: $T_m= \sqrt{6}T_e $.

Can anyone tell me how this equation is derived? This is how I tried to, but I got stuck after some time.

So the time period of a simple pendulum on the earth= $2\pi\sqrt{l/g}$

The time period of a pendulum on the moon is $2\pi\sqrt{l/(g/6)}$

Now how do I create an equation which shows the time period of a pendulum on the moon with respect to the time period of a pendulum on the earth.

And please be as detailed as possible!

Comment: The first time period is $T_e$ and the second is $T_m$, so what problem are you having?

Comment: Just divide one expression by the other, keeping in mind that $\sqrt {ab} =\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} $

Comment: The 6 is approximate, not exact. Writing $\sqrt 6$ wrongly suggests that it is exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the second formula:

$$T_m = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{l}{\frac{g}{6}}} = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{6l}{g}} = 2 \pi \sqrt{6\frac{l}{g}} = \sqrt{6} \left(2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}\right) = \sqrt{6} T_e$$

Comment: ahh this is what I was looking for! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there!

\begin{align*}
T_e&=2\pi\sqrt{\frac lg}\\
T_m&=2\pi\sqrt{\frac l{\frac g6}}=\sqrt6\cdot2\pi\sqrt{\frac lg}=\sqrt6\cdot T_e\\
\end{align*}